Marriage after 13 days of mourning period of death
My grandfather passed away on Tuesday at 2:53 am i.e. on the night between Monday (7th Oct) and Tuesday. Do we count the day of death as Monday as it happened before sunrise or Tuesday.
My sister is supposed to get married on 20th and we have the 13 day mourning period. Does that mean the wedding can happen on the 20th?

Sorry to hear the loss in your family.. I don’t see any muhurat in October due to chaturmasa.. Which calendar is followed in your area?? Also, this is personal advice Q which is off topic here, you should ideally consult some professional for this..

All auspicious functions like marriages should be postponed in such case for one year .. please ask your family priest.
